# setInterval + clearIntervalInside + parameters -no jquery-

Tags: javascript, parameters, dom-events, setinterval, clearinterval

I need to call a function periodically with `setInterval` and passing parameters to it. At the same time, I need to clear the interval inside the function that's being called when the mouse is moved.

So I'm trying this:

```
var timer = setInterval(function(x,y){ // When I use this, x and y are undefined.

  /*
   Code
  */

  document.getElementById("wholeDocument").onmousemove=clearInterval(timer);

  }, 50);
```

The idea is to know how to use setinterval with a clearInterval inside and being able to pass parameters.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: how will you get x and y

Comment: How do you intend to use it. Is it required?

Comment: x, and y are two variables with the coords of the mouse. that's actually working fine. It's something like this.

var e = event; 
var x=e.clientX; 
var y=e.clientY;

Comment: You may not want to bind mousemove in every interval function execute. It should be outside

Comment: What I'm trying to do is: There are 3 divs and they move towards the mouse pointer. So when the pointer is at let's say (150,300) the setInterval calls the function that makes the divs move. So if the mouse changes coords, the clearInterval triggers and it starts all over again. So x and y are the mouse coords everytime.

Comment: Got it. You would need to record and remember the x & y. Will edit my code.

Comment: Well actually, x and y are being refreshed all the time because each time you move your mouse over the document it gets the mouse coords. But I just can't pass the parameters  when I define the function inside setInterval, and I also need to do that to be able to clear it afterwards.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21226/discussion-between-raghavv-and-user1770660)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var timer = null;
document.getElementById("wholeDocument").onmousemove= function(evt) {
    if (timer) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      timer = null;
    }
    x = evt.clientX;
    y = evt.clientY;
    var timer = setInterval(function() { fnTimer(x, y); }, 50);
};

function fnTimer(x, y) {
  // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the concept which could possibly be improved depending on what you're trying to achieve, this line

```
document.getElementById("wholeDocument").onmousemove=clearInterval(timer);
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("wholeDocument").onmousemove = function(e) { clearInterval(timer); }
```